# symfony2 security firewall for DemoController

Tags: security, symfony

I've created a standard symfony edition project - 2.3.8 with standard demo and secured controllers

Is it possible to configure the security settings in a way, that user authenticated in SecuredController will be visible in DemoController as well?

DemoController should be also visible for not authenticated users.

when i set pattern to:

```
        secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/
```

demo isn't visible to not authenticated users, with different setting:

```
        secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured
```

user authenticated in SecuredCOntroller isn't visible in DemoController

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add another firewall for your non-secured area above the secured firewall setting:

```
      non_secured:
            pattern: ^api/public
            anonymous: true
```